# PHP GMail IMAP Connection Failure

Tags: php, gmail-imap

I am using this [repo](https://github.com/SSilence/php-imap-client) for connecting to the gmail. But its getting error. I hope someone has experience handling this recently.

```
<?php
    namespace program;

    require_once "php-imap-client/vendor/autoload.php";

    use SSilence\ImapClient\ImapClientException;
    use SSilence\ImapClient\ImapConnect;
    use SSilence\ImapClient\ImapClient as Imap;

    $mailbox = 'imap.gmail.com';
    $username = 'alice@gmail.com';
    $password = "wonderland";
    $encryption = Imap::ENCRYPT_SSL;

    // Open connection
    try{
        $imap = new Imap($mailbox, $username, $password, $encryption);
        // You can also check out example-connect.php for more connection options

    }catch (ImapClientException $error){
        echo $error->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
        die(); // Oh no :( we failed
    }
```

Comment: What error is it getting?

Comment: errflag=1 and avoided encryption to use 143 port too, then got errflag=2.

Comment: errflag? I don't know what that is. What is `error->getMessage()` giving you?

Comment: Error connecting to {imap.gmail.com/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}
PHP Notice:  Unknown: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this before too. From the link in the error message you're receiving.

> Allow less secure apps: If you don't use 2-Step Verification, you
>   might need to allow less secure apps to access your account.

[Here's a guide to do so](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)